# Cacti Login Page: Infinite loop occurs

Tags: centos, cacti

Apache 2.2.3 | PHP 5.1.6 | MySQL 5.0.77

I followed [cacti installation guide](http://www.cacti.net/downloads/docs/html/install_unix.html) to install latest cacti 0.8.7h on CentOS 5.5 (64-bit). The installation of PHP/Apache/MySQL went smoothly until I finished the setup, and came to the login page.

I can login *http://.../cacti/index.php* with admin account but the new page is redirected to the same login page with the message "Please enter your Cacti user name and password below"

This is a infinite loop!

If I use a wrong admin password I get the correct error message "Invalid User Name/Password Please Retype". [Same problem [here]](http://forums.cacti.net/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=40424)

If I login use Guest/guest account, "Error: Access Denied, user account disabled." displays.

The Cacti log file (./cacti/log/cacti.log) is empty.

I Googled and seems this problem has existed for a long time, but no followup solutions were found on the forum posts I found. Anyone can help me on this problem? If more information needed, please let me know.

---

Nov 18, 2011 UPDATE: I re-installed Cacti, this question remains **UNSOLVED**.

Answer (score 1):

try to enable session.auto_start on php.ini or check your session.save_path

Comment: Enable session.auto_start does no help.
session.save_path = "/var/lib/php/session", should I change it?

Comment: BTW, for the "Required Packages for RPM-based Operating Systems", when I verify the package **httpd** and **net-snmp**, the following displays: `[cacti]# rpm -V httpd
S.5....T  c /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
`
`[cacti]# rpm -V net-snmp
S.5....T  c /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf
S.5....T    /usr/share/snmp/mibs/.index
`

What does that indicate and will it be the problem?

Comment: should be not problem. /var/lib/php/session <= is it writable by apache ?. i got the same problem with you last time. i checked on database cacti i was login successfully ( select * from user_log, you should see the result field, if it's 1 it's mean successfully ), but on the frontend it's still showing login page.

Comment: Login successfully but return to login page, that's exactly the problem I'm facing. Have you solved this problem last time? Would it be a good idea to "yum install cacti"?

Comment: yes, i solved it with change  session.save_path to /tmp/, and enable session.auto_start. after you login successfully, check /tmp/ it's should be have file sessions like SESS_xxxx. i'm not sure you can install via yum (cmiiw, if you can it could be using old version).

Comment: I changed session.save_path to /tmp/, and SESS_XXXX files were generated, but that does no help to solve the login problem :( BTW, installation guide suggests that "If using PHP 4.3.5 or less include the following line. If using 4.3.6 or greater, you should remove this line if present.  session.save_path=/tmp"

Comment: make sure selinux disabled, try to reinstall php and cacti, or use yum install cacti. is there any proxy in front of your httpd ? (varnish/squid/any proxy), if yes, try to disabled it ?

Answer (score 1):

Login as admin, click on "User Management"
Select the user you're trying to authenticate with.
On the right corner click on: 
chose an action -> Enable -> Go

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth taking a look at the domain of cookies returned by cacti and at what domain you actually use to open it. Helped in my case.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was caused by an errant rule in my Varnish configuration which was stripping out cookies with `unset req.http.cookie;` and `unset beresp.http.set-cookie;`.  Varnish sits in front of everything, including Cacti, and needed to exclude Cacti from this rule.

Making the conditionals around these directives more restrictive fixed Cacti for me.